# How to set parseUserAgent to true in express for express-device

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent

I've  been looking at express-device and I can get it to work fine if I just want the device type.

```
var device = require('express-device');

app.use(device.capture());

device.enableViewRouting(app);

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.json({"Message" : "Hello World !"});
    var accessDate;
    accessDate = new Date();

    console.log("Device Type: " +  req.device.type.toUpperCase() + " Device Name:" + req.device.description + " Date: "+ accessDate.toDateString());
    console.log(req.device);

})
```

my req.device looks like the  following

```
{ parser: 
   DeviceParser {
    options: 
     {  emptyUserAgentDeviceType: 'desktop',
        unknownUserAgentDeviceType: 'phone',
        botUserAgentDeviceType: 'bot',
        carUserAgentDeviceType: 'car',
        parseUserAgent: false },
        make_sure_parser_was_executed: [Function],
        get_model: [Function],
        get_type: [Function] 
     }, 
  type: 'desktop',
  name: '' 
}
```

If I want to get the device name or description I need to set **parseUserAgent** to true. My question is how do I do this? Perhaps its just been a long week and I'm being a bit brain dead but for the life of me I can't see how you set this.

Answer (score 0):

Settings such as `parseUserAgent` can be set by passing an options object to the middleware when it's setup to be used:

```
app.use(device.capture({
  parseUserAgent: true
}));
```

[From the module's readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-device#how-to-use-it):

> Since version 0.3.4 you can now override some options when calling **device.capture()**. It accepts an object with only the config options (the same that the `device` supports) you which to override [...]. The ones you don't override it will use the default values.